# Integer overflow int and char

Tags: integer, overflow

I have two examples:

```
unsigned long l = ULONG_MAX; 
char c = -1; 
if (c == l)
    std::cout << "-1 = 4,294,967,295?";
```

output:"-1 = 4,294,967,295?"

```
unsigned char l = 255; 
char c = -1; 
if (c == l)
    std::cout << "-1 = 4,294,967,295?";
```

output:

Why first example generates output but second not?

Answer (score 0):

C compiler converts the examples:
In first case :
`if ((unsigned long)c == l)`

In second case
`if ((int)c == (int)l)`